# iOS : Device having 7.0.2 not detected in XCode 5

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I updated my iPad 2 OS to version 7.0.2 and updated XCode 4.6 to XCode 5. Device is detected in iTunes, but not in XCode 5 and I get an age old message `No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version.`

I see a valid provisioning profile in Windows->organizer. I closed the XCode and started again but device not detected.

What might be the issue?

Comment: Also, try to upgrade your Xcode version. Apple is repeatedly trying to improve security. I know all these stuffs, because i am myself very much concern about securities

Comment: Yes...thats right...upgrade Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

check in your Xcode Development Target  [image]

match your iOS version with Development Target

its work for me